# Determine If Row is Selected in DataGrid

Tags: datagrid, vb6

So I have a simple DataGrid with a few fields and I want to put a "Delete row" button.
I know how to do everything but check if there aren't any rows selected in the DataGrid..

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The `.Row` property of your grid will return the index of the currently selected row in the grid.  If it's < 0, there is no selection.